# Phonegap Facebook plugin is not working on real device

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I've a got the Facebook plugin for Phonegap working on Android Simulator, but it's not working on my mobile (Xperia Neo), when i want to login no popup show and it redirect me to browser and shows a classic 404 error page for:
fbconnect://success#access_token=CAAFTr6h...AtO3NsmgZDZD&expires_in=51...9

And on logcat : Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

Thank you.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the facebook app on my phone to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you do not have the actual Facebook app installed on your device. The SDK checks for the Facebook App installed on your real device. If it is found, it will make the requests via Facebook App. So, just check whether you have the Facebook application on your phone. However, it is not necessary that you have to have the app installed on your phone. The SDK can handle the requests by itself.

Few things you might want to look at:

- Make sure you have given the correct App ID.
- Make sure you have the
  permission for Internet in your AndroidManifest file.
- Check the Hashkey is correct